# Узнать ширину отрисовки строки, не зная контекста?

Tags: изображения, java, строки

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Дано:

`public static Font FONT = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 400);` с учетом того, что шрифт и размер может меняться в рантайме.

`public static String TEXT = "SomeString";` с учетом того, что строка может меняться в рантайме.

Нужно:

Создать BufferedImage с размерами, совпадающими с размерами отрисованной строки указанным фонтом.

Имага создается в потоке, потоку известно только вышеуказанное.

Сейчас делаю это "костылем":

```
finalImage = new BufferedImage(
    (int) ( Config.FONT.getSize() * (Config.TEXT.length()) * 1.5 ),
            Config.FONT.getSize() * 2,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
          );
```

Есть вариант узнать баунды строки, зная контекст, но контекст ещё не создан...

Хотелось бы узреть варианты, как ещё можно узнать ширину строки.

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без контекста узнать не получится. Контекст (`Context`) в числе прочих содержит в себе данные о конкретном окружении где будет разворачиваться ваш текст.

Как только приложение запущено контекст на самом деле уже известен, его например, можно вытащить из `Application.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Спасибо, самое оно.